# Change drill down level for multiple charts at the same time

Tags: looker-studio

I am looking for a way to change multiple charts at the same time from, e.g., daily to monthly.

I can use the drill down functionality to change the drill down level of a single chart. But I don't know if and how to apply the drill down level to multiple charts at the same time.

The only solution I have found is to create multiple pages - in my example one page for daily data and another page for monthly data - and then maybe add a button / link to move from one page to the other. However, that seems awefully cumbersome.

Any good solutions out there?

Comment: There is an easy way to create a drill down function, if you have your data aggregated at the levels you want eg having a month AND a day in your data table, along with a field that states if the data is daily or monthly , you can filter on that field to change the data in the charts. If you can't change the data before you load it, there is a way to achieve this with blends but its complicated

Comment: Thanks @Max_Stone, that's a smart solution. Why don't you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to create a drill down function, if you have your data aggregated at the levels you want eg having a month AND a day in your data table, along with a field that states if the data is daily or monthly , you can filter on that field to change the data in the charts. If you can't change the data before you load it, there is a way to achieve this with blends but its complicated